# Parsing props and functions with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a little problem here when making my portfolio.
I'm trying to trigger a function in App.js but it has to be triggered when clicking a child child.
Here is my App.js

```
class App extends Component {

  introref = React.createRef()
  timelineref = React.createRef()
  projectref = React.createRef()
  skillsref = React.createRef()
  certifref = React.createRef()
  downloadref = React.createRef()

  blah = (link) => {
    scrollToComponent(this.link, { duration: 1600 })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Route path="/textversion" component={TextVersion} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        <Navbar introref={this.introref}
          timelineref={this.timelineref}
          projectsref={this.projectsref}
          skillsref={this.blah.bind(this, this.skillsref)}
          certifref={this.certifref}
          downloadref={this.downloadref}
          onClickFunction={this.blah.bind(this, this.props.onClickFunction)}
        />
        <Title content="I am Tristan Vermeesch" />
        <hr />
        <Bio />
        <Introduction ref={this.introref} />
        <Timeline ref={this.timelineref} />
        <Projects ref={this.projectsref} />
        <Skills ref={this.skillsref} />
        <Certificates ref={this.certifref} />
        <Download ref={this.downloadref} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The function that needs tobe called here is blah, link is the ref of the element.

Here is my navbar

```
class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        const { introref, timelineref, projectsref, skillsref, certifref, downloadref } = this.props
        return (
            <div className="navbar" >
                <Link to="/textversion" className="link">Text Version</Link>
                <Link to="/contact" className="link">Contact</Link>
                <Navitem dName={"Resume"} onClickFunction={this.downloadref} />
                <Navitem dName={"Certificates"} onClickFunction={this.certifref} />
                <Navitem dName={"Skills"} onClickFunction={this.skillsref} />
                <Navitem dName={"Projects"} onClickFunction={this.projectsref} />
                <Navitem dName={"Life"} onClickFunction={this.timelineref} />
                <Navitem dName={"Me"} onClickFunction={this.introref} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And here is the navitem, the item that should trigger the function onClick

```
class navitem extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="navItem" onClick={this.props.onClickFunction}>
                    {this.props.dName}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Can someone please clear everything out, because I tried to understand the whole props thing but I still don't understand.

Comment: Does your `Navbar` component implement `onClickFunction` function?

Comment: @MarcoS The onClickFunction is only in App.js

Comment: So `onClickFunction={this.blah.bind(this, this.props.onClickFunction)}` should be `onClickFunction = {this.blah.bind(this, this.onClickFunction)}`...

Comment: In which class should that be? Put that in the navbar so it triggers that function in it's parent?

Comment: It's fine if it is in App Component...

Comment: @MarcoS it don't change anything

Answer (score 0):

In the `App` component, change the `onClickFunction` prop to :

```
onClickFunction={this.blah}
```

In the `Navbar` component, change the `Navitem` like this :

```
<Navitem dName={"Resume"} onClickFunction={this.props.onClickFunction.bind(this, downloadref)} />
<Navitem dName={"Certificates"} onClickFunction={this.props.onClickFunction.bind(this, certifref)} />
<Navitem dName={"Skills"} onClickFunction={this.props.onClickFunction.bind(this, skillsref)} />
<Navitem dName={"Projects"} onClickFunction={this.props.onClickFunction.bind(this, projectsref)} />
<Navitem dName={"Life"} onClickFunction={this.props.onClickFunction.bind(this, timelineref)} />
<Navitem dName={"Me"} onClickFunction={this.props.onClickFunction.bind(this, introref)} />
```

Comment: I tried that and then added `skillsref={this.blah.bind(this, this.props.skillsref)}` into the navbar but still nothing, no errors

Comment: Also tried ` onClickFunction={this.blah.bind(this, this.props.onClickFunction)}` in app.js but no result

Comment: could you please reproduce the problem in https://codesandbox.io/s/new , and share the link with us ?